# Undo changes of a set of selected files in VS Code Git

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, undo

I have accidentally run eslint fix in my React.js app and now have about 160 files been changed, but they are not relevant to the branch that I'm currently working on. Therefore I have to undo the file changes, but reverting files one by one takes a lot of precious time and there are some file changes that I need to keep.

How can I undo only a set of selected changed files *at once* in the VS Code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend:

- stashing files you want to keep (which you can do with [GitLens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens#gitlens))
- hard restting to a previous commit
- applying your stash

That way, you don't have to revert files one by one.

Comment: Yeah, I could have done that, but I didn't remind it today morning, so I reverted files one by one, all 160. Btw thanks for your answer. I thought there is no way to do this. However, it would be better if there was such an option in VS Code source control GUI.

Comment: @Pavindu Indeed, that would be easier.